# Mit dem Bus / mit einem Bus

Tags: article

I've noticed that it is far more common to say "*Ich komme mit **dem** Bus*" than to say "*Ich komme mit **einem** Bus*". So I wondered:

- is it ok at all to say "mit einem Bus"?
- if it's ok, does it have a completely different meaning?

Since one normally comes with a general unknown bus, not his father's bus, say, I would expect that one will come with "**einem**" bus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*mit dem Bus* means "by bus", *mit einem Bus* means "in a bus". *Mit dem Bus/Zug/Auto/Fahrrad* is just the fixed expression meaning "by bus/train/car/bicycle".

Here and in other places, ***dem*** is a definite article, but doesn't specify a particular bus, but rather buses in general. On the other hand *in einem Bus* would mean "in a particular, but undisclosed, bus".

I think the same happens in English:

> I'm in **the** car at the moment. Can I call you back?
> Ich bin im Moment im Auto. Kann ich dich zurückrufen?
>
> I'm in **a** car at the moment.
> Ich bin im Moment in einem Auto.

The latter sounds like you are in a particular, but unspecified, car.